# Prevent page jumping in Chrome when tabbing to offscreen elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, focus

Run the following in Chrome, and press **Tab** until the window scrolls:

```html
<ol>
  <li><input type="text" autofocus></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li>
</ol>
```

Note how the focused element jumps up to the middle of its window.  This makes data entry annoying, so I'd rather the page scroll up smoothly, keeping the newly focused element at the bottom.  This seems to occur in Chrome only.

I can prevent this behavior with JavaScript:

```js
$(document).on('focus', 'input', function() {
  let top = $(this).parent().position().top,
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
      inputHeight = $('input').height(),
      windowHeight = $(window).height();

  if (top < scroll + inputHeight) {
    window.scrollBy(0, -inputHeight);
  } else if (top > scroll + windowHeight - inputHeight * 2) {
    window.scrollBy(0, inputHeight);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li><input type="text" autofocus></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li>
</ol>
```

But I'm wondering if there is an HTML or CSS solution.  (I would also settle for a more elegant JavaScript solution.)

---

**Edit**

I've come up with a much simpler solution, but it has the side-effect of the page scrolling one pixel for each Tab (or Shift+Tab) press:

```js
$('input').keydown(function(evt) {
  if(evt.key == 'Tab') {
    window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY + (evt.shiftKey ? -1 : 1));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li><input type="text" autofocus></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I don't see a difference between the behavior of the two snipets of code

Comment: I'm running Chrome 64.0.3282.167 on ubuntu

Comment: @RickHitchcock It's hard to tell the difference unless you paste the code into a separate HTML file or tab slowly (instead of holding down the tab button as you instructed).

Comment: Thanks, @hev1, I've changed to "repeatedly press the **Tab** key."

Comment: @RickHitchcock No problem.

Comment: ok, pressing repeatedly (quite slow) I see the difference

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://jsfiddle.net/monim67/ya73cu4f/)?

Comment: Thanks, @MunimMunna, but I'm looking to prevent the page from jumping up when you tab to the bottom of the screen, not when you tab to the bottom of the inputs.

Comment: I didn't get it, what is the difference? Are you dealing with elements with `tabIndex`? What do you mean by *prevent the page from jumping up*? Scrolling to top? Or doing nothing?

Comment: Run the first Snippet without expanding it.  Tab down to row 11.  Note how it jumps up to the middle of its window.  I want to avoid that, because it's very annoying when doing data entry.  This seems to happen in Chrome only.

Comment: Your solution is still the best in my opinion, to be ideal I'd change the calculations in a way that the element starts to scroll in the middle of the page, not when we reach the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, @Emeeus.  I'd rather it scroll when at (or near) the bottom, to be consistent with most other programs that accept data entry (spreadsheets, databases, word processors, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a pure CSS solution.

Simply changing the height of the input on focus, even slightly, solves the problem:

```css
input:focus {
  background: yellow;
  transform: scaleY(1.00001);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li><input type="text" autofocus></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li>
</ol>
```

Here's why it works:

When focusing a partially-offscreen element, Chrome scrolls only as much as is needed.  When focusing a completely-offscreen element, Chrome scrolls it to the center of the screen.

By increasing the height on focus, the window scrolls if needed to accommodate the newly-focused element.

When you Tab to the next element, the previous element reverts to its previous height.  But the window has already scrolled enough so that the next element is already partially in view.

That's enough to prevent Chrome from scrolling it to the center of the screen.

This works for both Tab and Shift+Tab.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need JS here, as Chrome supports `scroll-behavior` property:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><input type="text" autofocus></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @RickHitchcock, I believe that Chrome developers added this behaviour for a reason. I guess that many people found it useful. In other hand, Firefox does not have this feature. So your question looks like opinion-based to me.

Answer (score 2):

HTML/CSS cannot help in this matter, you have to take care of it with JavaScript. The simplest one I can think of is using `Element.scrollIntoView()` method.

> **[Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)**
>
> The Element.scrollIntoView() method scrolls the element on which it's called into the visible area of the browser window. It is experimental API as of today, but supported by most of modern browsers including chrome. (*[See Browser Support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility)*)

```js
(function ($) {
    var shouldScroll = false;
    $(document).on('focus', 'input', function () {
        if (shouldScroll) {
            this.scrollIntoView(false);
            shouldScroll = false;
        }
    });
    $(document).on('keydown', 'input', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 9) shouldScroll = true;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li><input type="text" autofocus></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li><li><input type="text"></li>
</ol>
```

**Note:** View the snippet in Full-Page/Expand-Snippet mode.

Comment: Thanks, `scrollIntoView` positions an element at the top or bottom of the screen.  Your solution works great for **Tab**, but not quite so well for **Shift+Tab**.  (The cursor stays at the bottom unless you're on the first  screen.)  `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` seems promising, but I haven't had luck with it.

Comment: I actually thought the cursor staying at bottom was a good idea from the perspective of data-entry. `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded` will not work, as the `input` jumps to middle, scrolling is not needed, it took me a while me to figure it out.

Comment: It's not necessarily a *bad* idea.  But try this: Run your Snippet fullscreen, and tab to line #80.  Now click #60.  Note how the cursor jumps to the bottom of the screen.  That could be confusing for someone doing data entry.  The screen should scroll only when needed – and it should do so smoothly – like Excel or Google Sheets.  (Be interesting to see how Google handles this for Google Sheets.)

Comment: I have noticed that, this is because `scrollIntoView` is called even when the input is focused by a click, but it should not. I am looking into it already, will update you when I get to anything.

Comment: Wouldn't be difficult to cancel the event on click.  But you'd then need to deal with **Shift-Tab** – but *only* if the element is already on screen.  By then, the code may become as complicated as the code I'm already using.

Answer (score 1):

This is smooth for tabbing forward (tab) or backwards (shift+tab).

At first it is calculated which 'pixel' or 'index' is the first and the last visible one.

Then a comparison is made if the desired pixel/index fits within that range.

If not -> an adjustment is done.

```
$('input').focusin(function(e) {
  let height = $(window).height();
  let scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  let position = $(this).position().top;
  let elementHeight = $(this).height();

  let firstVisibleIndex = scroll;
  let lastVisibleIndex = scroll + height;  
  let additionalSpace = 5 * elementHeight;

  let newScrollTop;

  if(position + additionalSpace > lastVisibleIndex) {
    newScrollTop = position - height + additionalSpace;
  }

  if(position - additionalSpace < firstVisibleIndex) {
    newScrollTop = position - additionalSpace;
  }

  $(window).scrollTop(newScrollTop);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yo12fgLj/115/

Comment: Thank you.  This is similar to my solution for **Tab** (and I had a similar solution for **Shift-Tab** that I didn't post).  Still hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: I've updated my post with the code I'm using in production.  I had simplified it for the purpose of posting, so I'm sorry you spent time recreating what I already had done.

Comment: Well no need to be sorry, it was good practice anyway. I'm also interested if there is another approach of solving this.